# How to count checkboxes in a row (pure javascript)?

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript beginner, and believe that the answer actually is simple, but I really can't think of anything. I've been stuck with this for a couple of days.

I have a table, that I have created with JavaScript. In this table I have checkboxes and I must read how many boxes are checked in a row and in a column. I made a function that can read all the ticked boxes, but I can't think of a function that counts ticked boxes in a row and in a column.

I have added my code down below. There are some places where I have commented a code out, because it just doesn't work, but maybe something in this is still right.

```js
function tabel(r, c, conteiner) {
  out = document.getElementById("out"); //out väljastab sisestatu
  r = document.getElementById("r").value;
  c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  tab = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tab.border = "1";
  tb = document.createElement("TBODY");
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement("TR");
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      td = document.createElement("TD");
      chk = document.createElement("input");
      chk.type = "checkbox";
      if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == c - 1)) {
        //JÄÄB NII
        td.innerHTML = "";
      } else if ((i == 0 && j > 0) || (i > 0 && j == 0 && i != r - 1)) {
        td.innerHTML = "select/unselect column ";
      } else if (i > 0 && j != 0 && j != c - 1 && i != r - 1) {
        td.innerHTML = i + " - " + j;
        td.id = "t_" + i + "_" + j;
      }
      if (
        (i == 0 && j > 0 && j != c - 1) ||
        (i > 0 && i != r - 1 && j != c - 1)
      ) {
        //chk.type="checkbox";
        chk.row = i;
        chk.column = j;
        chk.id = "c_" + i + "_" + j;
        td.appendChild(chk);
      }

      chk.onchange = function() {
        all(this, r, c);
        row(r, this);
      };
      chk.onchange = row(r, this);

      // if ((i>0 && j==(c-1))||(j>0 && i==(r-1))){
      //chk.onchange=row(r,this);
      // }

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tb.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tab.appendChild(tb);
  document.getElementById(conteiner).appendChild(tab);
}

function all(ob, r, c) {
  if (ob.row == 0) {
    checkCol(ob.column, r, ob.checked);
  } else if (ob.column == 0) {
    checkRow(ob.row, c, ob.checked);
  }
  sum(c, r);
}

function sum(c, r) {
  s = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < r - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < c - 1; j++) {
      ob = document.getElementById("c_" + i + "_" + j);
      //ob=document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
      if (ob.checked == true) {
        s++;
      }
      // td.innerHTML=s;}
      // if (j==c)
      td.innerHTML = s;
    }
    //td.innerHTML=s;
  }
  // td.innerHTML=s;
}

function checkCol(ci, r, b) {
  for (var i = 1; i < r - 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("c_" + i + "_" + ci).checked = b;
  }
}

function checkRow(ci, c, b) {
  for (var i = 1; i < c - 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("c_" + ci + "_" + i).checked = b;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="r">
<input id="c">
<button onclick="tabel(r,c,'out')">Genereeri tabel</button><br>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Miising code.  `row(r, this)` error while running code

Comment: The JS representations of table row elements have a `rowIndex` property, and table cells have `cellIndex`. So you could just loop over _all_ checked checkboxes, go up to the containing table cell and row, grab the index from there, and then you’d know which counter values inside an array you’d have to increment by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using most of your original code:

```js
function tabel(r, c, conteiner) {
  out = document.getElementById("out"); //out väljastab sisestatu
  r = document.getElementById("r").value;
  c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  tab = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tab.border = "1";
  tb = document.createElement("TBODY");
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement("TR");
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      td = document.createElement("TD");
      chk = document.createElement("input");
      chk.type = "checkbox";
      if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == c - 1)) {
        //JÄÄB NII
        td.innerHTML = "";
      } else if ((i == 0 && j > 0) || (i > 0 && j == 0 && i != r - 1)) {
        td.innerHTML = "select/unselect column ";
      } else if (i > 0 && j != 0 && j != c - 1 && i != r - 1) {
        td.innerHTML = i + " - " + j;
        td.id = "t_" + i + "_" + j;
      }
      if (
        (i == 0 && j > 0 && j != c - 1) ||
        (i > 0 && i != r - 1 && j != c - 1)
      ) {
        //chk.type="checkbox";
        chk.row = i;
        chk.column = j;
        chk.id = "c_" + i + "_" + j;
        td.appendChild(chk);
      }

      chk.onchange = function() {
        all(this, r, c);
      };

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tb.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tab.appendChild(tb);
  document.getElementById(conteiner).appendChild(tab);
}

function all(ob, r, c) {
  if (ob.row == 0) {
    checkCol(ob.column, r, ob.checked);
  } else if (ob.column == 0) {
    checkRow(ob.row, c, ob.checked);
  }
  sum(c, r);
}

function sum(c, r) {
  s = 0;
  var sC = [0]; // sum of columns Array index 0 useless except following sums are indexed by table column index
  for (var i = 1; i < r - 1; i++) {
    var sr = 0; // sum of this row
    for (var j = 1; j < c - 1; j++) {
      if (sC.length <= j) sC.push(0);
      ob = document.getElementById("c_" + i + "_" + j);
      if (ob.checked == true) {
        s++;
        sr++;
        sC[j]++;
      }
      td.innerHTML = s;
    }
    ob.parentElement.nextSibling.innerText = sr; // .TD.next.text
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < c - 1; j++) {
      tab.rows[tab.rows.length-1].cells[j].innerText = sC[j];
  }
}

function checkCol(ci, r, b) {
  for (var i = 1; i < r - 1; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById("c_" + i + "_" + ci);
    el.checked = b;
    el.onchange();
  }
}

function checkRow(ci, c, b) {
  for (var i = 1; i < c - 1; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById("c_" + ci + "_" + i);
    el.checked = b;
    el.onchange();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="r">
<input id="c">
<button onclick="tabel(r,c,'out')">Genereeri tabel</button><br>
<div id="out"></div>
```